# hosts.deny line too long or too big file?

Tags: linux, hosts, deny, denyhosts, hosts.deny

I have about 50k ip addresses denied in the hosts.deny file, generated by a script with 7 addresses per line max and get this error:

```
warning: /etc/hosts.deny, line 4429: missing newline or line too long
```

Line 4429 is the one in the middle here:

```
ALL: 96.47.225.95, 96.47.225.96, 96.47.225.97, 96.47.225.98, 96.47.225.99, 96.56.113.123, 96.8.112.149
ALL: 98.126.161.178, 98.15.206.118, 98.159.4.16, 98.197.212.67, 98.83.135.94, 98.94.6.213, 98.94.6.78
ALL: 99.167.89.146, 99.177.96.73, 99.235.84.25, 99.244.9.103, 99.49.94.70
```

whats wrong?

**Update:**

The warning only appears when at the moment a connection is made up, the hosts.deny file gets written at the same time. (i/o, lock, fopen for write, fopen for read problem).

Comment: You are the most dedicated person I have ever met.

Comment: Dude, why are you not denying IPs in blocks instead of one at a time?

Comment: Yeah. That makes no sense to go one by one.

Comment: I have different tools, servers and sources reporting bot and evil ip addresses into a single database, and a cron that generates hosts.deny and ipset rules from that table. Not all servers are able to use iptables. I don't know any tool building blocks of given addresses
I don't want to lock a whole block when there's only 2-3 bad ip's in it. :-S

Comment: @ChrisS what tool can you suggest to sum up single ips to groups?

Comment: Perhaps I should ask why you're using hosts.deny instead of iptables?

Comment: @ChrisS I have root servers with iptables support but some virtual servers without iptables support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to have such a large `/etc/hosts.deny' file for several reasons:

1. botnet activity can come from possible legitimate sources IP addresses, and it is usually useless to forever block an IP that can just be the temporary public IP of a compromised home computer with dynamic address.
2. there are better tools for this job, like `denyhosts`, `fail2ban`, `psad`, etc... that will provide some protection from the evil doers, without falling in the trap mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Now, if you really need to maintain such a file, you could try to use a file, as explained in the `hosts_access(5)` manpage, under the `PATTERNS` section:

> PATTERNS
>
> ```
>  The access control language implements the following patterns:
>
>   ·      A  string  that  begins  with a `/´ character is treated as a file name. A host name or address is matched if it matches any host name or address pattern listed in the named file. The file format is zero or
>           more lines with zero or more host name or address patterns separated by whitespace.  A file name pattern can be used anywhere a host name or address pattern can be used.
> ```

I gave it a try, and generated a list:

```
# echo 123.{1..255}.{1..255}.{1..254} > /etc/list
```

Added it to the `/etc/hosts.deny` file:

```
# echo 'ALL: /etc/list' >> /etc/hosts.deny
```

Tried some connections and inspected my logs. I haven't been able to reproduce the warning you mentioned.

Comment: 1. I don't keep my logs and bans forever. 2. Why u think fail2ban is better when you don't even know my setup? I AM using fail2ban on one of the servers. fail2ban adds ip's to the database and hosts.deny!

Comment: Fair enough. Did you try to use a separate file to maintain the list? did it work?

Comment: I didn't try that. But I will go for that, create a temporary list and `mv`it over the hosts.deny

Comment: I had a look at this question again after years and I pretty much laughed at the comments and the way I tried to defend my server :D Using fail2ban for a long time now and it works great.

Comment: So what's the line length limit of hosts.deny?  This doesn't answer his question.